# How can I deploy a non HTTP network application on Cloud Foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry, paas

I am in process of setting up a local Cloud Foundry instance and while going through the documents I noticed that the router description states that it routes the incoming HTTP request to the applications and then I tried to google and found some similar answers that **CF can only accept HTTP/S traffic.**

**I want to deploy my SIP application which usually runs on UDP and port 5060.**

Now I think that it is not possible to deploy my service on CF.

Can some CF experts comment whether or not it is possible to deploy on CF services other than HTTP based or standalone?

Is this the case with every PaaS? Please suggest some alternatives or workarounds.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the product manager for the Cloud Foundry routing tier.

We're currently adding support for TCP routing to Cloud Foundry; it may be user-facing by the end of the year. You can try it out already with Lattice [1].

Routing of UDP requests to applications running on Cloud Foundry is not currently on the roadmap, but I will record your use case.

Best,
Shannon Coen

[1] http://lattice.cf/